# Fill array list with two array in adapter?

Tags: android, json, arraylist

My problem is when I set this two array in one list I cant get proper value of this two array.

Below is my json response which I get from server.
`User_Label_List` is not always getting but `Admin_Label_List` array is common.

```
{
    "User_Label_List": [
        {
            "iLabelID": "60",
            "vLabel": "At Ground"
        }
    ],
    "Admin_Label_List": [
        {
            "iLabelID": "53",
            "vLabel": "At School"
        },
        {
            "iLabelID": "51",
            "vLabel": "At Office"
        },
        {
            "iLabelID": "52",
            "vLabel": "At Work"
        },
        {
            "iLabelID": "50",
            "vLabel": "At None"
        },
        {
            "iLabelID": "49",
            "vLabel": "At Home"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this my code.

```
try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Admin_Label_List");
                        labelarray = new ArrayList<LabelModel>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            labelModel = new LabelModel();
                            JSONObject labeljson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    //                      lableList.put("iLabelID", labeljson.getString("iLabelID"));
    //                      lableList.put("vLabel", labeljson.getString("vLabel"));
                            labelModel.setLabelId(labeljson.getString("iLabelID"));
                            labelModel.setLabelName(labeljson.getString("vLabel"));
                            labelarray.add(labelModel);
                        }

                        Log.e("length", "== "+jsonObject.length());
                        if (jsonObject.length() == 2) {

                        String arryName = jsonObject.names().getString(1);
                        if (arryName.equalsIgnoreCase("User_Label_List")) {
                            JSONArray userjsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("User_Label_List");
                            userlabelarray = new ArrayList<LabelModel>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < userjsonArray.length(); i++) {
    //                          userLabelModel = new UserLabelModel();
                                JSONObject labeljson = userjsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    //                          lableList.put("iLabelID", labeljson.getString("iLabelID"));
    //                          lableList.put("vLabel", labeljson.getString("vLabel"));
                                labelModel.setLabelId(labeljson.getString("iLabelID"));
                                labelModel.setLabelName(labeljson.getString("vLabel"));
                                userlabelarray.add(labelModel);
                            }

    //                      userlabelarray.addAll(labelarray);
                        }
                        List<LabelModel> union = new ArrayList<LabelModel>(labelarray);
                        union.addAll(userlabelarray);
                        customeLabelAdpater = new CustomeLabelAdpater(ChooselabelActivity.this, lableList);
                        listView.setAdapter(customeLabelAdpater);
                        }
```

so can any one suggest me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing your `LabelModel` in second time, while you are filling your second array data, Can you please reinitialize your `LabelModel`,

don't worry about previous data you already filled, so while filling next array data you have to reinitialize your `LabelModel`, hope it will work.